# Why does Logstash write into two indices? (default and custom ones)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using Elasticsearch 5.2 and Logstash 5.2 .

My problem is that Logstash is writing into the default index (format logstash-2017.02.15) and into my custom one.
I just want it to write **only** into my "logstash-secure" index. How can I do?

Here is my simple configuration:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
        index => "logstash-secure"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

PS: if you tell me that I have to use a custom template, could you please explain me why? :)

Comment: As far as I know *logstash* doesn't have any default index to be written over, unless you specify it within the *conf* or manually create it. Didn't you create the **logstash-2017.02.15** indice? By means it's getting created along with **logstash-secure** when executing the above *conf*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution out.
Actually I had two configuration files but I thought there was no incidence.

I solved my issue with the conditional statements. Then, Logstash store informations into two different indices depending on the source.

Here is my new first conf file:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
        add_field => { "log_type" => "apache" }
    }
}
filter {
[some conf]
}
output {
    if [log_type] == "apache" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
        }
    }
}
```

And my second conf file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/secure"
    start_position => "beginning"
    add_field => { "log_type" => "secure.log" }
  }
}
filter {
[some conf]
}
output {
        if [log_type] == "secure.log" {
           elasticsearch {
               hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
               index => "logstash-secure"
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: Try to be hyper-aware of any and all configurations. What much of the documentation for Logstash fails to mention is that two configurations can affect eachother (e.g. if you have two configs with the same input and filter, but a different output).